# Accessing variables from other viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interact with a view controller from another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319876/interact-with-a-view-controller-from-another-view-controller)

viewcontrollerOne.h

```
UILabel *label;
```

viewcontrollerTwo.m

```
-(void)myMethod
{
 viewControllerOne *obj = [[viewControllerOne alloc]init];
 obj.label.text = @"abcd";
}
```

I want to access variables of one viewcontroller in other view controller.I tried the above method but it's not working for me.i searched other threads but most of the answers told me to declare them in appdelegate. so is there any other way instead of declaring it in appdelegate?

Comment: And many, many others. Alloc/init creates **a new instance** of an object, it does not refer to the original view controller.

Comment: I am not able figure out the answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You code is wrong, you should have labelOne, not label:

```
obj.labelOne.text = @"abcd";
```

Also, your label may not exist yet - do you create it in the init function?  If you have a xib file for that controller then you need to load that so that all the controls are created and linked up:

```
viewcontrollerOne *controllerNew = [[viewcontrollerOne alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontrollerOne" bundle:nil];
```

Also, it would be much nicer to declare your label as a property rather than a member variable:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *labelOne
```

Then synthesize the setter/getter methods in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize labelOne;
```

Finally, Cocoa naming standards are that class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: i did all those sir,i just posted a little bit of code.my problem is to access that variable in other viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

create a new method in viewcontrollerTwo (don't forget to declare it in *.h file):

```
-(id) setParams:(UILabel *)lb{
   labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   labelOne = lb
   return self;
}
```

Then, when you need to puth this view controller from first one:

```
    viewcontrollerTwo *controllerNew = [[viewcontrollerTwo alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontrollerTwo" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerNew animated:YES];
    controllerNew = [controllerNew setParams:labelOne];
    [controllerNew release];
```

Answer (score 0):

See its very easy... you can do it through App Delegate class.

Write the Variables which you want in appDelegate class like in .h

```
UILabel *myLabel;

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;
```

IN .m File :-

```
synthsize myLabel;

myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
```

Now in Whichever viewController u need to get this Label do this way :-

in .h file :-

```
@class AppDelegateClass; //forward decleration

AppDelegateClass *appDelegate;
UILabel *localLabel;     //CurrentViewController Label

//Make Property
```

in .m File :-

```
//synthesize the Label

appDelegate = (AppDelegateClass *)[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate];

//now to acccess it

localLabel = appDelegate.myLabel;
```

and Finished...

Hope it helps and if then **Please Tick as Correct Answer and UpVote the Answer**.... :)

Comment: this is just horrible coding style

Comment: Actually i am not so much professional in iPhone but could you please tell me then what are standards of coding in iPhone then??

Comment: in short: do not misuse your app delegate as the one-and-only singleton. do not misuse your app delegate for holding the model/data.

Comment: Ok... but if we are having 2-3 Variables which i want to use as static means Accessible anywhere then is it fine?? What we use then for Accessing variables anywhere from any ViewController?

Answer (score -2):

Please try below code instead of your code. and it will work fine...

```
viewControllerOne *obj = [viewControllerOne alloc];
obj.variableName = @"abcd";

[obj initWithNibName:@"nibName"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Who down vote this? Whats the wrong in this?